Movie where a character talks about a mystery river
I remember this movie where the main character is telling a story from his childhood to a group of kids:

As a child I knew there was a hidden river in the forest and I kept looking for it. One day I found it and I swam in it. 
  Then after some time, a group of military men and experts arrive at our village to explore it. I spoke with the main man (or the so called expert) and told him about the hidden river.
  The man told me gruffly that there was no such river. It is not on the map. I kept insisting that I did swim in this river, but the man just did not believe me.
  I then addressed my dad and told him: Dad, this man does not think the hidden river exists. Dad just smiled and told me: Son, what do I say, he is the "expert".

The person now tells the group of kids: Never believe the so-called "experts", because they never "swum" in any river?
Other details about the movie:
The movie is about a family in village and their life in the village. This was an English movie in color.
If I remember right the plot involves the man has grown up daughter. This daughter is married. Her husband has an affair with the village prostitute. The daughter then confronts the prostitute and realizes that she is stuck in a love-less marriage.
I do not remember the actor, nor the entire plot.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

How do you remember a whole dialog paragraph of a movie, but don't remember the title of it?

@GustavoGabriel: If it helps your offended sensibilities, I do believe he was paraphrasing.
